# Read the Sub String and tag the found rows as Sub string

Tags: excel, vba

VBA code needs to Read the Sub String in the cells, If Sub String found , Need to tag the found rows as Sub string in next column.
This is my code: But its not considering if sub string in lowercase and If their no Space as well.

```
Sub KeyWord_II_TheSequel()

    Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long, ary, s As String
    Dim r As Range, a, i As Long, outpt As String
    Dim Tags As Worksheet
    Dim Datasheet As Worksheet

    Set Tags = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Taglist")
    Set Datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Na = Datasheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Tags.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim ary(1 To Nc)
    i = 1
    For Each r In Tags.Range("C1:C" & Nc)
        ary(i) = r.Text
        ary(i) = " " & ary(i) & " "
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    For i = 1 To Na
        s = Datasheet.Cells(i, "B").Value
        s = " " & s & " "
        outpt = ""
        For Each a In ary
            If InStr(1, s, a) > 0 Then
                outpt = outpt & "," & a
            End If
        Next a
        If outpt = "" Then
        Else
            Datasheet.Cells(i, "C").Value = Mid(outpt, 2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Example:- 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISBLu.png)

My Output should be like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMphg.png)

Comment: Would help *a lot* to show sample data...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function  there is a fourth parameter which controls case-sensitivity of `Instr`

Comment: You should edit your question to add the sample data - it's impossible to read in comments

Comment: i have added example file.

Comment: I am able to fix the Issue -  If InStr(1, s, a, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

Comment: If you just want the first word in the "Description" Column, you don't need VBA. you can do it with excel function. To extract the first word from cell B2, the function is `=MID(B2,1,FIND(" ",B2,1)-1) ` To extract the second word from cell B2, the function is `=MID(MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2,1)+1,LEN(B2)),1,FIND(" ",MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2,1)+1,LEN(B2)),1)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long, ary, s As String
Dim r As Range, a, i As Long, outpt As String
Dim Tags As Worksheet
Dim Datasheet As Worksheet

Set Tags = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Taglist")
Set Datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data table")

Na = Datasheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Nc = Tags.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

ReDim ary(1 To Nc)
i = 1
For Each r In Tags.Range("C1:C" & Nc)
    ary(i) = r.Text
    'ary(i) = " " & ary(i) & " "
    ary(i) = " " & ary(i) & " "
    i = i + 1
Next r

For i = 1 To Na
    s = Datasheet.Cells(i, "B").value
    s = " " & s & " "
    outpt = ""
    For Each a In ary
        'If InStr(1, s, a) > 0 Then
        If InStr(1, s, a, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            'outpt = outpt & "-" & a
            outpt = outpt & "-" & a
        End If
    Next a
    If outpt = "" Then
    Else
        Datasheet.Cells(i, "C").value = Mid(outpt, 2)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.